# mod_python can't see my Django project settings file

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-python

I need to deploy my Django application on my apache server, I've added the following to my httpd.conf:

```
<Location "/dashboard/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    PythonPath "['/home/firas/project/trunk/dashboard/analytics','/home/firas/project/trunk/dashboard', '/home/firas/project/trunk'] + sys.path"
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE dashboard.settings
    PythonOption django.root /dashboard
    PythonDebug On
</Location>
```

I am getting the following error when requesting my app:

```
mportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named settings
```

My settings.py has no syntax errors.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

if you want apache to see dashboard.settings, the PythonPath should end at "project/trunk".

You can use either

```
PythonPath "['/home/firas/project/trunk'] + sys.path"
SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE dashboard.settings
```

or

```
PythonPath "['/home/firas/project/trunk/dashboard/analytics','/home/firas/project/trunk/dashboard', '/home/firas/project/trunk'] + sys.path"
SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE settings
```

The first one is better, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but for me it was apache permissions.

```
chmod o+x settings.py
```

Fixed it.